# Comparing Elements across collections

Tags: sql, postgresql, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Collection(models.Model):
     ...

class Record(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, related_name='records')
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    checksum = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('filename', 'collection'),)
```

I want to perform the following query:

For each `filename` of `Record` I want to know the `Collections` that:

- Do not provide a `Record` with that filename
- *or* that provide such a `Record` but has a differing `checksum`

I have in mind an output like that:

```
           | C1  C2   C3    <- collections
-----------+------------
file-1.txt |     x     
file-2.txt |     x     
file-3.txt | !   !    !
file-4.txt | x   !    !
file-5.txt | !   !    x

x = missing
! = different checksum
```

What I've com up so far is that I create a query for each `Collection`, excluding all filenames that are within this collection but exist in others.

```
for collection in collections:
    other_collections = [c for c in collections if c is not collection]
    results[collection] = qs.filter(collection__in=other_collections).exclude(
        filename__in=qs.filter(
            collection=collection
        ).values_list('filename', flat=True)
    ).order_by('filename').values_list('filename', flat=True)
```

This somewhat solves the first part of my question, but is rather quirky and requires post-processing to get to the format I desire. And, more importantly, it does not address the `checksum` comparison.

Is it possible to perform the two queries in one combined step to get the results in the format I described above?

The solution would not necessarily have to use the `QuerySet` APIs, a fallback to raw SQL is fine by me too.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to write a SQL query that returns a variable number of columns, although you can achieve that effect if you wrap everything in [an array](http://illuminatedcomputing.com/posts/2013/03/fun-postgres-puzzle/) or JSON object.

If you know the collections, you could write SQL like this:

```
SELECT r.filename,
       (SELECT r.checksum = r2.checksum FROM records r2 WHERE r.filename = r2.filename AND r2.collection_id = 1) AS c1, 
       (SELECT r.checksum = r2.checksum FROM records r2 WHERE r.filename = r2.filename AND r2.collection_id = 2) AS c2,
       ...
FROM   records r
WHERE  r.collection_id = 1
GROUP BY r.filename, r.checksum
```

For each filename/collection pair, you will get `NULL` if the collection doesn't have the record, `true` if the collection has it with the right checksum, or `false` if the collection has it with a different checksum.

I include `WHERE r.collection_id = 1` because otherwise for the checksum comparison, you have to answer "different from what?"